# Laravel old input array select

Tags: php, laravel, select

I am trying to keep input from multi select dropdown, using old(). Anyway to get the selected values highlighted

```
<select name="contract_id[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
    @foreach($contracts as $contract)
        @if( ( isset($usercontract) && $usercontract->where('id' , $contract->id) != "[]" ) ||
                                            ( count($errors) && old('contract_id[]') == $contract->id ) )
           <option value="{{ $contract->id }}" selected="">{{ $contract->name }}</option>   
        @else 
          <option value="{{ $contract->id }}">{{ $contract->name }}</option>
        @endif

    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Google: `laravel multiselect old`

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution used in_array() function in php.

```
<select name="contract_id[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
      @foreach($contracts as $contract)
          @if( ( isset($usercontract) && $usercontract->where('id' , $contract->id) != "[]" ) ||
                       ( count($errors) && in_array($contract->id, old('contract_id')) == $contract->id ) )
              <option value="{{ $contract->id }}" selected="">{{ $contract->name }}</option>   
          @else 
              <option value="{{ $contract->id }}">{{ $contract->name }}</option>
          @endif

       @endforeach
</select>
```